# MySQL - delete where not in find_in_set

Tags: mysql, find-in-set

I'm trying to find the right syntax to delete records that are not in a comma separated row.

**table A**

```
| id | product_id | attribute_id |
|----|------------|--------------|
| 1  | 123        | 45           |
| 2  | 123        | 46           |
| 3  | 124        | 34           |
| 4  | 124        | 33           |
```

**table B**

```
| code | Axis  |
|------|-------|
| 123  | 45,46 |
| 124  | 34    |
```

My goal is to remove all rows from table A where the attribute id is not in the table B axis value (in this example the row with id = 4).

I try to do a `SELECT` before:

```
SELECT A.attribute_id, A.product_id
FROM tableA as A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM tableB) AS B
ON FIND_IN_SET(A.attribute_id, B.`axis`)
```

But without any luck.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following to `SELECT` the data:

```
SELECT A.attribute_id, A.product_id 
FROM tableA AS A LEFT JOIN tableB AS B ON A.product_id = B.code
WHERE IFNULL(FIND_IN_SET(A.attribute_id, B.Axis), 0) = 0
```

You can use the following to `DELETE` the rows on table A (based on `SELECT`):

```
DELETE FROM tableA WHERE id IN (
    SELECT A.id 
    FROM tableA AS A LEFT JOIN tableB AS B ON A.product_id = B.code
    WHERE IFNULL(FIND_IN_SET(A.attribute_id, B.Axis), 0) = 0
)
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a3e13/6/0

Comment: Perfect ! work like a charm. many thanks for your quick and very usefull help.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
DELETE FROM tableA WHERE id IN
(
 SELECT A.id
 FROM tableA AS A
 LEFT JOIN tableB AS B
 ON A.product_id = B.code AND FIND_IN_SET(CONCAT(A.attribute_id), B.Axis) = 0;
)
```

If your `attribute_id` field is char or varchar, just ignore the `CONCAT` function.