# delete rows where id is in a comma delimited string

Tags: php, mysql

I need to delete all rows where id is in a comma delimited string.

```
$ids = '1,2,3,4,5'; 
$sql = "delete from images where id in(:aid)";
$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute([
    ":aid" => $ids
]);
```

Result - only one row is deleted.

Comment: If you use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-find_in_set) then you can treat your comma delimited string as a string.

Comment: `$ids = explode(',',$ids);`?

Comment: If you want to use `find_in_set`, here's an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560910/mysql-delete-where-not-in-find-in-set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) along with [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$st->execute([
    ":aid" => "'".implode("','", explode(",",$ids))."'"
]);
```

Or use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-find_in_set)

```
$sql = "Delete from images WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`id`, :aid)";
$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute([
   ":aid" => $ids
]);
```

Comment: finally works, thank a lot